# Why does Identifier extend Declaration in the TypeScript Compiler?

Tags: typescript, compiler-construction

In the TS compiler internals, the type of the AST node for `Identifier` extends `Declaration`:

```
export interface Identifier extends PrimaryExpression, Declaration {
    ...
}
```

Why?

In the actual AST in the public API, `const x = 3` (the entire range) is a `VariableDeclaration` and the `x` part is the `name` property of the declaration of type `Identifier`.  So why would `Identifier` itself be a Declaration in [src/compiler/types.ts](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/9bd23652ef8c4e6a614a2f27c467b1a68ce3340e/src/compiler/types.ts#L759)?